# Where to have email service in ASP project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dry

I have a WEB Api project. Different places in the project, it sends an email to a user.

The code could look like this standard code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

In my project, where is the correct place to create and have this method? In a folder called "Services" with a file called EmailService.cs, with the above code, or what is the best/correct practice, to keep code DRY?

Comment: Seems more like an opinion question to me. Side note, all your configuration for SMTP can be placed in the web.config. See [<smtp> Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: why don't you create a class with a static method and have  your email logic in one place and construct your dynamic email messages.. I will post an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `utils` with a static method like so:

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(utilities.EmailHost, 25))
    using (var message = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(utilities.FromEmail),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        foreach (var address in utilities.RecipList.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            message.To.Add(address);
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

to call the method something basic like this

```
SendEmail("this is a test email.","this is my test email body");
```

Comment: So, you would suggest a "utils" folder in the project with a Email.cs as above?

Comment: no I would suggest a `utils.cs` file that's accessible throughout the entire project utilizing the same `namespace` as your project.. in your case `EmailService.cs` would be a public class and you would add the methods above in that class file.. you right click on your project and select add new item, then select `Class File` then when you name it `EmailServiceUtils` for example the IDE will generate the class file with the proper `namespace`

Comment: Where do you place a file like that?